# String indices must be integers and while issue

Tags: python

I am writing some code for school homework. The assignment is this:
Write a code which will read book codes till "000" is entered and then split the books into two categories depending on the first 4 digits entered ISBN and ISSN.

**NOTE**: Use str and check the prefix of the code (in which case ISBN and ISSN).

Here is my code:

```
bookarray = []
booknumber = str(input("Give me a book code - Type 000 if you want to cancel"))
while booknumber != "000":
   bookarray.append(booknumber)
   booknumber = str(input("Give me a book code - Type 000 if you want to cancel"))
   if booknumber[0,4] == "ISBN":
       isbnarray = booknumber
   elif booknumber[0,4] == "ISSN":
       issnarray = booknumber
print(issnarray)
print(isbnarray)
```

Any help regarding the same would be appreciated! I am in my first year in python at school.

EDIT: The expected output should be two lists with the books' code numbers. 
Currently, I face an autonomous loop on "while" which I am not sure of how and why.

Comment: What exactly are your expectation here ?

Comment: try `booknumber[:4]` instead of `booknumber[0,4]`

Comment: My expectation more or less is to have books with the first four digits added being ISSN being added to the issnarray and ISBN added to isbnarray

Comment: @PitoguroGR generally speaking other SO users will not appreciate being asked to solve the homework problems of other people. However, you made some effort to describe your problem and you were upfront about the origin of your question, so fair play to you! 
What you could do is try to make your question even more clear and provide examples of the expected user input (the ISBN numbers) and explicitly show what the output should be. 
http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @feedMe Thanks for clarifying, I know and I was sure that there would be some users not appreciating me asking to solve my homework. Though it's quite complicated that the assignment will ask the use of str with quite many issues involving that. It's either my fault, the teacher's/book's or compiler's fault and that is after all why I originally made a post here. We have not be taught any other way to "ask" the user to input stuff than str and int.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ is a good starter guide to debugging. If I were in your shoes, I'd start by `print`ing out values as they are used: `bookarray`, `booknumber`, `booknumber[1,4]` etc. to make sure they contain what I think they contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if booknumber[0,4] == "ISBN":
```

You're passing a `tuple` as index to `booknumber` which explains the error message ("indices must be integers"). You want a *slice*:

```
if booknumber[0:4] == "ISBN":
```

In that case you'd be better off with

```
if booknumber.startswith("ISBN"):
```

Also, if you're using python 2, entering `000` and passing it to `str(input())` just yields `"0"` since `input()` evaluates your expression and `000` is just `0`. It's OK for python 3, but for python 2, switch to `raw_input()` (or just ask user to enter `0` to quit, and test for `"0"` for instance. BTW `input` is unsafe in python 2).

Comment: Thanks, I just noticed, thing is that now while will go on a loop entering 000 will not stop

Comment: smells very much like that. Can you try `input()` and type `000` to see what happens?

Comment: Thanks yet again, though raw_input is not defined and I am pretty confident that it was removed. 

I am using Pyzo 4.3.1 and Python 3.4.5 yep tried with input() still a loop